# Numerical method for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral

I accounter the problem of calculating Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)$ numerically, where $f(x)$ is a differentiable with any order, and  $g(x)$ is a monotone non-decreasing function, $f(x),g(x) \geq 0, \forall x$. Is there any reference (article or book) about this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is $g(x)$ fixed? Is it possible to determine moments $\int_a^b x^m dg(x)$ analytically?

Comment: What have you tried? Basically Gaussian Quadrature works also under that setting (under additional assumptions).

Comment: @uranix: g(x) is fixed. There is no way to calculate analytically the integral you suggested.

Comment: @user251257: How does  Gaussian Quadrature work in this case? I only knew this method can be used for approximating the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$. Do you know any reference about it?

Comment: Cf gauss quadrature in Wikipedia. You could use a lower formula on a fine partition to approximation the Integrals which are needed to compute a higher order formula. However in most applications you low order formula are sufficient.

Comment: If $g$ is smooth just consider $\int fg'$

Comment: Please, provide us with an example of function $g(x)$ you're dealing with